# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table error but table exists

Tags: magento-1.9

Here's the complete error, the table exists and I'm able to run this query from myphpadmin

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Booomchik.mage_rating_option_vote_aggregated' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM `mage_rating_option_vote_aggregated` WHERE (entity_pk_value = 63) AND (rating_id IN('1', '2', '3'))
```

This happens when I delete products. They delete but with this error.
So the product does get deleted from Mage_catalog_product_entity table and then I guess tries to delete some relates records in other tables and can't find this table though it does exist.

Yesterday I created a new database, imported all my tables there and changed the prefix. I'm new to magento and web, I know this was a bad way of doing it but I was afraid to just rename, wanted to be able to fall back if something went wrong. 
Changed it in local.XML file too, so I don't think this is thr problem.

Deleted the var\cache directory, as suggested on a diff question.

Edit. Here's a screenshot of me running the query

[image]

Comment: as per as concept. my  may check  in wrong database.You need  check current  used db at local.xml (app/etc/)

Comment: I think I did. The error is listing correct db and prefix, so I think I did it right and its looking to the right db

Comment: What is the name of your current db prefix `mage_` setting in magento?

Comment: Booomchik is the new db and mage_ is the new prefix. BoomchikMage was the old db and mage2_ was the old prefix.

Comment: Does the username/password that magento uses to connect to the database have the correct privilege? Try correct with your magento credential  manually using shell

Comment: I think it does. Will check now. Look at the edit to the original question, posted a screenshot. Edit I don't know how to use shell, googling, might take a little bit to figure out

Comment: Are you connected with the same magento (mysql) username and password and from the same server? Also try deleting the content of you magento var/cache/* folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29050/discussion-between-lalachka-and-r-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating that the table does not exist which could be either permission issue or typeo.

Try ssh into your server the and log into mysql using your magento credential

```
mysql -u username-from-local.xml -p
```

Then

```
select * FROM `Booomchik.mage_rating_option_vote_aggregated` WHERE (entity_pk_value = 63) AND (rating_id IN('1', '2', '3'));
```

Comment: It's not permissions but running this sql helped me figuring it out, my table had an apostrophe at the end. I'm sorry, really dumb question. I'm working on my phone and long table names are cut off. I saw most of the table name and assumed the rest is correct too. Then my copy and paste was glitching so I edited the sql with the table name already there instead of typing it or pasting from magento error.